# Why rpy2 use way too much RAM

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm trying to setup rpy2 on my computer.

My config:

- Windows 10, 16Go RAM
- Anaconda: 4.4.0 with python 3.6
- An independant R version: 3.4.1

Python packages:

- rpy2: 2.8.6
- pandas: 0.20.3

First thing i do is to load my data set (adult from UCI repo):

```
import pandas as pd
original_data = pd.read_csv(
    "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",
    names=[
        "Age", "Workclass", "fnlwgt", "Education", "Education-Num", "Martial Status",
        "Occupation", "Relationship", "Race", "Sex", "Capital Gain", "Capital Loss",
        "Hours per week", "Country", "Target"],
        sep=r'\s*,\s*',
        engine='python',
        na_values="?")
original_data.head()

import sys
sys.getsizeof(original_data)
>> 34605590
```

Now that i have imported my data set that is not that big...
Now i start R interface as shown in [rpy2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html)

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

Control R memory limit (result in Mo)

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r('memory.limit()')
>> array([ 2047.])
```

2Go i should be safe... I try to pass my data set to R.

```
r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(original_data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-5921ca574db2> in <module>()
----> 1 r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(original_data)

C:\Users\touleem\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    801 
    802     def wrapper(*args, **kw):
--> 803         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    804 
    805     registry[object] = func

C:\Users\touleem\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\pandas2ri.py in py2ri_pandasdataframe(obj)
     58             od[name] = StrVector(values)
     59 
---> 60     return DataFrame(od)
     61 
     62 @py2ri.register(PandasIndex)

C:\Users\touleem\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\vectors.py in __init__(self, obj)
    956                                  " of type VECSXP")
    957 
--> 958             df = baseenv_ri.get("data.frame").rcall(tuple(kv), globalenv_ri)
    959             super(DataFrame, self).__init__(df)
    960 

RRuntimeError: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 254 Kb
```

Please note that before failling, my RAM usage exploded (from 5Go to 16Go :O).

Why does it take so much RAM?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it take so much RAM?

Unfortunately, I don't have ant idea. `rpy2` is not really supported on Windows (meaning native, works fine in a Docker container).

The following is working fine here (meaning way less memory usage than what you are reporting):

```
url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')
dataf = utils.read_csv(url)
```